# Reading in checkbox values in c# using selenium

Tags: c#, excel, selenium, checkbox

Hi I am working on a Test automation project using c# and selenium. I am reading the values from an excel file, however I am having trouble reading in checkbox values, I am not sure how to dynamically read the values. in a simple case scenario here is my current source code:

```
class LoginPageObject
{
    public LoginPageObject()
    {
        PageFactory.InitElements(PropertiesCollection.driver, this);
    }


    [FindsBy(How = How.CssSelector, Using = "[customid = '5624']")]
    public IWebElement selectCheckbox { get; set; }

    [FindsBy(How = How.Name, Using = "UserName")]
    public IWebElement txtUserName { get; set; }

    [FindsBy(How = How.Name, Using = "Password")]
    public IWebElement txtPassword { get; set; }

    [FindsBy(How = How.Name, Using = "Login")]
    public IWebElement btnLogin { get; set; }


    // Method to Perform Login
    public PageObject Login(string userName, string password)
    {
        //Select checkbox
        selectCheckbox.Click();

        // Send Username 
        txtUserName.EnterText(userName);

        // Send Password 
        txtPassword.EnterText(password);

        // Click Login Button
        btnLogin.ClickSubmit();

        return new PageObject();
    }
}
```

This works fine, however I want to take a more dynamic approach where the custom id is not hard coded, something like this:

```
    class LoginPageObject
{
    string value = "5624";
    public LoginPageObject()
    {
        PageFactory.InitElements(PropertiesCollection.driver, this);
    }


    [FindsBy(How = How.CssSelector, Using = "[customid = '"+ value + "']")]
    public IWebElement selectCheckbox { get; set; }

    [FindsBy(How = How.Name, Using = "UserName")]
    public IWebElement txtUserName { get; set; }

    [FindsBy(How = How.Name, Using = "Password")]
    public IWebElement txtPassword { get; set; }

    [FindsBy(How = How.Name, Using = "Login")]
    public IWebElement btnLogin { get; set; }


    // Method to Perform Login
    public PageObject Login(string userName, string password, string value)
    {
        //Select checkbox
        selectCheckbox.Click();

        // Send Username 
        txtUserName.EnterText(userName);

        // Send Password 
        txtPassword.EnterText(password);

        // Click Login Button
        btnLogin.ClickSubmit();

        return new PageObject();
    }
}
```

it is obvious that the source code above won't compile, but I was wondering how to approach this so that the checkbox isn't hard coded in a way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The FindsBy annotation only can use a const string as the Using parameter. This is also evaluated at compilation time.
When you do not use the Page Factory it is possible. You just find the checkbox like this:

```cs
string value = "5624";
IWebElement checkbox = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("[customid = '"+ value + "']"));
checkbox.Click();
```